# using setInterval and setimeout to make 3 components load after each other

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a simple react app, it just loads one component when it reached 100% then it loads the second one and after its 100% it loads the third one.

this is how it works, I have a start button, when you click it, it starts the first function which loads the first component:

```
<Button
            variant="outlined"
            type="submit"
            onClick={() => {
              setLoading(true);
              start();
            }}
          >
            Start
          </Button>
```

and here are the loading components they are all the same expect the state is different:

```
  const load1 = () => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setProgress1((prevProgress) =>
        prevProgress >= 100 ? 100 : prevProgress + 10
      );
    }, 800);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  };

  const load2 = () => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setProgress2((prevProgress) =>
        prevProgress >= 100 ? 100 : prevProgress + 10
      );
    }, 800);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  };

  const load3 = () => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setProgress3((prevProgress) =>
        prevProgress >= 100 ? 100 : prevProgress + 10
      );
    }, 800);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  };
```

and my start looks like this:

```
  const analyseDNA = () => {
    setTimeout(load1, 2000);
    setTimeout(setLoading2(true), 2000);

    setTimeout(load2, 4000);
    setTimeout(setLoading3(true), 4000);

    setTimeout(load3, 6000);
  };
```

what is supposed to happen is to load component 1 and then component 2 and then component 3 after each other. then you can press start again and it does the same.

however, with this code, component 1 and component 2 are loaded together, and then after 6 seconds component 3, when you press start again it only loads component 1, and component 3 is already loaded and nothing happens with component 2. when I open console I can see that it is printing 1, 2, 3, and it seems like the interval is never ends and it keeps going , how can I fix this?

Comment: What is the return value of `setLoading2(true)` and  `setLoading3(true)`? [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#syntax)  expects as its 2nd argument a number type. And how about using `Promise`s? Since the OP mentions ... *"to make 3 components load after each other"* ... and in case one knows or is notified about a loaded component choosing a promise based approach migth be even cleaner tha just random/guessed delays.

Comment: when loading2 is true is shows the component 2 and after that is fully loaded, then loading 3 is now true to show the component 3

Comment: is it not possible with a callback, to make sure load1 is done then load2 is run and then finally load 3?

Comment: The OP might consider editing the questions in order to explain in clear and simple words what a component does, how it loads and what determines its loaded state. After this one could go more in a components detail. BTW ... in addition to each `setLoading` functionality the implementation of each `setProgress` function is a blackbox to this audience too.

Comment: Is this line `setTimeout(setLoading2(true), 2000);` meant to be this: `setTimeout(() => setLoading2(true), 2000);` ?

Comment: @Steve yes I think I can also write it like that.

Comment: @S.N ... *"yes I think I can also write it like that"* ... nope, there is just one correct way.

Comment: @PeterSeliger i am making it more clear, however the loading are just loading from material ui, there is nothing specific about it, when u click on start it starts loading  untill it reaches 100% then the other loading starts, if you look at the code the setinterval make sure the loading indicator is being fielded, and the point is when it reaches 100% just load the other component.

Comment: Yea it's just being invoked when that line is created, not when the code gets there. I would be using promises, they make the most sense for this application. I'll have a go at writing up an answer for using callbacks

Comment: @steve wont it be too complicated with promise?

Comment: Promises are a bit more difficult to learn but once comfortable with them, I think they are much simpler.

Comment: @S.N ... *"wont it be too complicated with promise"* ... Since it's an abstraction it makes every task easier which is covered by such an abstraction. Thus for the OP's problem one needs to either know for sure when a component has finished loading, or even better already has a component which allows a callback for its finished loading state. This allows for explicitly resolving each promise within a chain of promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made you a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/setinterval-component-load-ybchu?file=/src/App.js). Could be prettier but it should get you on the right path. The trick would be to pass in a callback function to the load function. When the loader reaches 100 from the interval, invoke that callback which calls the next loader.

Personally, I think promises are more suitable. You would do something along the lines of creating a set interval inside a promise, then resolve the promise when the value reaches 100. This way you could make your `analyseDNA` function more like this:

```
  const analyseDNA = async () => {
    await load1()
    await load2()
    await load3()
  };
```

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/setinterval-component-load-promise-1k1cr?file=/src/App.js) for a "promise" approach. Of course, you might need to adapt if you want to show progress.